# How to resize grid cells to fit their contents? I have spent couple days now trying to figure this out now

Tags: css

> I'm trying to resize my grid cells to fit their contents but when i gave them heigh induvidually it distored the whol layout. I have a grid container that has two container inside. the first one is a grid container and the second one is a flex box
> take a look at my css maybe I got the layout wrong `.

```
mycontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.mycontainer > div {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
.boxe1 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

.seconContainer > div {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
.boxe1 {
  height: 435px;
}
.boxe5 {
  height: 535px;
}
.seconContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.bigcontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 25px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .bigcontainer {
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

> here is my HTML

```
   <div class="bigcontainer">
      <div class="mycontainer">
        <div class="boxe1"> 
          <p><br/></p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.<br/>
             Aliquid sit provident doloremque vitae deserunt<br/> rerum placeat
              neque tenetur, atque
             unde. Dolores consectetur,<br/> assumenda animi aliquid incidunt 
             enim nam natus sunt.</p><p><br/></p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.<br/>
              Aliquid sit provident doloremque vitae deserunt<br/> rerum placeat
               neque tenetur, atque
              unde. Dolores consectetur,<br/> assumenda animi aliquid incidunt 
              enim nam natus sunt.</p><p><br/></p>
       
        </div>
        <div class="boxe2">
        <img src="textimages/box3.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"/>
        </div>
        <div class="boxe3">
          <img src="textimages/box3.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="seconContainer">
        <div class="boxe4">
          <img src="textimages/box4.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="boxe5"> 
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.<br/>
            Aliquid sit provident doloremque vitae deserunt<br/> rerum placeat
             neque tenetur, atque
            unde. Dolores consectetur,<br/> assumenda animi aliquid incidunt 
            enim nam natus sunt.</p><p><br/></p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.<br/>
             Aliquid sit provident doloremque vitae deserunt<br/> rerum placeat
              neque tenetur, atque
             unde. Dolores consectetur,<br/> assumenda animi aliquid incidunt 
             enim nam natus sunt.</p><p><br/></p>
         
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]
`

this is what I'm trying to achieve
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you and i used sample images

> I used flex box for responsive instead of grid.

```css
 * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
body{
overflow:hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
            .bigcontainer {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                width: 98vw;
                height: 100vh;
                font-family: 'sans';
            }

            .bigcontainer::after {
                content: '';
                background: #f6f2ea;
                width: 60%;
                height: inherit;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: -1;
                right: 0;
            }

            .bigcontainer > div {
                width: 50%;
                height: 50%;
                padding: 15px;
            }

            .box2 img {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

            .box3 {
                display: flex;
                gap: 10px;
            }

            .box3 img {
                width: 50%;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
                .bigcontainer > div {
                    width:100%;
                    height: max-content;
                    flex: 0 0 100%;
                }

                .box2 {
                    order: 4
                }

                .box3 {
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                }

                .box3 img {
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .bigcontainer::after {
                    display: none;
                }
            }
```

```html
<div class="bigcontainer">
            <div class="box1"> 
               <h2>Title</h2>
                <p>Lorem apsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.<br/>
                   Aliquid sit provident doloremque vitae deserunt<br/> rerum placeat
                    neque tenetur, atque
                   unde. Dolores consectetur,<br/> assumenda animi aliquid incidunt 
                   enim nam natus sunt.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.<br/>
                    Aliquid sit provident doloremque vitae deserunt<br/> rerum placeat
                     neque tenetur, atque
                    unde. Dolores consectetur,<br/> assumenda animi aliquid incidunt 
                    enim nam natus sunt.</p>
             
              </div>
             <div class="box2">
                <img src="https://static.asianpaints.com/content/dam/sleek/kitchen-landing/TheRomantic%20Inspiration.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
              </div>
             <div class="box3">
                <img src="https://cdn.onekindesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Small-Kitchen-Ideas-01-1-Kindesign.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"/>
                <img src="https://cdn.onekindesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Small-Kitchen-Ideas-01-1-Kindesign.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"/>
              </div>
             <div class="box4"> 
                 <h2>Title</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.<br/>
                  Aliquid sit provident doloremque vitae deserunt<br/> rerum placeat
                   neque tenetur, atque
                  unde. Dolores consectetur,<br/> assumenda animi aliquid incidunt 
                  enim nam natus sunt.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.<br/>
                   Aliquid sit provident doloremque vitae deserunt<br/> rerum placeat
                    neque tenetur, atque
                   unde. Dolores consectetur,<br/> assumenda animi aliquid incidunt 
                   enim nam natus sunt.</p>
               
            </div>
```